# AngularJS : TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'replace'

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here's my problem :

I use Angular and **I try to implement ngTagsInput directive** (http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/). The problem I'm facing is try to retrieve results from a service, with this controller :

```
dashboardApp.controller('TagsCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
      $scope.tags = [];
      $scope.loadTags = function(query) {
        $scope.results = $http.get( '/search/autocomplete?q=' + query); // also tried with $http(); same thing
        return $scope.results;
        console.log($scope.results);
      };
    });
```

In the view, **the autocomplete "kinda works"**, it provides a droplist with a lot of [Object Object]. So I guess I'm pretty close, but the console throw this error ( console.log($scope.results);) :

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'replace'
```

The HTML part, if you need it :

```
 <div class="modal-body" id="ng-tags-input-container" ng-controller="TagsCtrl">
                                <tags-input ng-model="tags">
                                  <auto-complete source="loadTags($query)"></auto-complete>
                                </tags-input>
                              </div>
```

I hope someone can help, this is driving me crazy.

Comment: Try moving the `console.log($scope.results);` above the return statement and see what it says

Comment: As expected, it returns the same errors :)

Comment: You've obviously left out some code here. Either you have to post the rest of the code or you have to provide a stack trace. There's no calls to any `replace` function in there. What does `tagsInput` and `autoComplete` do? Sometimes I wonder how anyone can expect an answer when providing so little information...

Comment: I provide those informations : replace comes from AngularJS (I guess), tagsInput and autocomplete come from ngTagsInput directive (I gave a link to the project). I'm not sure I have to post AngularJS source and ngTagsInput directive source ?

Comment: Are you sure that your ajax result is an array of strings? The autocomplete showing [Object] makes me think they're something other than strings.

Comment: The Ajax result is a regular JSON, so I guess it's ok, but I can copy/paste a part of it if you think that can be relevant.

Comment: Well, ngTagsInput only works on simple arrays, like ['item', 'item', 'item'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a talk with Michael Benford, creator of ngTagsInput, and he said ngTagsInput can only work with simple arrays like : ['item', 'item', 'item'];

In my case, I got 2 solutions :

- making another service that return only the strings I need as an array
- I can convert my big json as a simple array with JS

Hope it will help someone :)